# Does Microsoft Moles Framework generate code coverage

Tags: code-coverage, moles, pex-and-moles

I have a simple test project using Moles and I have check the flag in the test settings to create code coverage but the Moles tests do not generate code coverage.

I'm not using Pex.

Does Microsoft Moles Framework generate code coverage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not as I understand it

You need to use a different tool for that. [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) and [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) are code coverage tools for .NET that will work with moles.

Try these previous questions [No Code Coverage Information for Tests Using Moles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013990/no-code-coverage-information-for-tests-using-moles), [NCover support with Moles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885612/ncover-support-with-moles) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385592/how-to-integrate-ncover-moles-mstest-to-get-the-coverage for starters